# Javascript program needs to add line to text file server side

Tags: php

I have a javascript learning game which is hosted on a web page
It maybe has a dozen users only, because its specialised, but I would like to log some data on how people are using it, e.g. how many questions they are answering etc.

All I wish to do is add some data to a mylog.txt file held on the server.
I have tried every thing, but nothing works. Ive been stuck on this a month+ so grateful if anyone can help

This was my simplest attempt..

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <body>
 <?php
  include "save.php";  // this is test just logging something to mylog.txt
 ?>

 </body>
 <canvas id="Canvas" ></canvas> // set up canvas to display
 <script>
 //quiz code goes in here
 </script>
</html>
```

Then I have save.php

```
<?php
 $log_file_name = 'mylog.txt'; 
 file_put_contents($log_file_name, "This works?", FILE_APPEND);
?>
```

It didn't work! :(
I'm not sure if I HAVE to use a POST command to send the data to save.php, and even then if that can be done automatically without having it linked to a form as I saw in one example

Comment: Use Google analytics or similar to log into external service

Answer (score 0):

hmm...

1st. change index.html to index.php

2nd.  Think  about it  as a "layers"

Your layer is  html/css/javascript  - the  thing  that  you are working  on.You write  a code  and it is  send to client  browse.

PHP is  layer "below" , it is  fired up  before sending  data to  client  blowser and it changes  your  layer.

Meaning?

will be changed   to  123  in the  data that is  sended to client  browser 

3.in php  file  you can have html/css/js . There is one thing  that you need  to remember   all php instruction need  to  be (beetween) in

Comment: Can javascript be in a .php file? I tried that and changing index to .php  did make log to the file work ... but then the javascripts not running???

Comment: if  you have in php something  like  echo '<script>js code </script>'   - then it should be  executed

Comment: ok I cut my quiz just down to drawing a box to test, and tried this.. but just get the word echo''  on the screen

Comment: <html>
 <body>
 <?php
  include "save.php";  // this is test just logging something to mlog.txt
 ?>

 </body>
 <canvas> id="Canvas" </canvas>

 echo '<script>
 var c1 = document.getElementById("Canvas");
 var ct1= c1.getContext("2d");
 ct1.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
 </script>'
</html>

Comment: nope  not like  this ,   echo  need to be in <?php  ?>

Comment: Why would you want to wrap your Javascript code inside `<?php` and `?>`?. Just remove `echo` and leave `<script> var c1 = document.getElementById("Canvas"); var ct1= c1.getContext("2d"); ct1.fillRect(0,0,100,100); </script>`. It should work since PHP files handle HTML too, and HTML can handle Javascript using the `<script>` tags.

Comment: Ah it works now, thank you both.
I used your simplification Condorcho, so Im bit surprised that javascript can go in .php file, so all those times I have differentiated between index.html and index.php I never really needed to?